# Order Unsaved siblings in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails app I have two models Student and Student Record.

in student.rb

```
has_many :student_records 
accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_records, allow_destroy: true
```

Now, in one of my modules, i have a method that checks for uniqueness of the ranges and I would like to pass it an ordered version of the sibligs(student_records).

```
validate :should_not_overlap
def should_not_overlap
  @ranges = []
  @counter = 0
  student_records.order(date_from: :asc).each do |sr|
    @ranges[@counter][sr.date_from] = sr.date_to
    @counter += 1
  end
  if over_laps?(@ranges)
    errors.add(:base, :should_not_overlap)
  end
end
```

But the ordering is not working. The over_laps? method is receiving an unordered version. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your student records are not saved yet you can try Array's method `#sort_by` instead:

```
student_records.sort_by(&:date_from)
```

I am not sure if ActiveRecord::Relation delegates the method correctly in all ActiveRecord versions. To be sure you can use `#to_a` before:

```
student_records.to_a.sort_by(&:date_from)
```

However, with Rails 4.1 this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: The problem I have now is during updating, student_records only gives me the previously saved ones, excluding the newly added records. How do I access the newly added records?

Comment: Hard to say without the code. Perhaps you should start a new question with the relevant code for that. However, if my answer solves your initial problem it would be nice if you accept the answer :)

Comment: Actually, with some miracle, your answer solves my second question as well. But I don't know why :-) Thanks

Comment: I think `student_records.order` recreates the association array based on the database table. Unsaved records will get lost because they are not in the database yet.